# SSRS expression for empty parameter value returns #Error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a parameter in report that I recently changed it to accept `NULL` values. It was a required parameter before but now it is not required. Header in the report has below expression to read data from the parameter value. Ever since I modified the parameter to accept `NULL`values, it is erroring out. It shows `#Error` in the header. I have tried modifying the expression to display result even if the parameter is 'NULL', but nothing has worked so far. I am pretty much stuck here. Here is the expression I am using in SSRS:

```
=IIF(Code.MultipleValues(Parameters!ProductID.Value(0))="True"
,IIF(IsNothing(First(Fields!ProductName.Value, "ProductHeader")),""
,First(Fields!ProductName.Value, "ProductHeader")).ToString
,IIF(Len(Parameters!ProductID.Value(0)) > 0
,IIF(First(Fields!ProductName.Value, "ProductHeader") is nothing,""
,First(Fields!ProductName.Value, "ProductHeader")),"All Products Selected"))
```

I believe the error has to do with the VB custom code that is in the report. I am not too familar with the code so I am having trouble troubleshooting it.
VB code:

```
Public Function MultipleValues(ByVal str As String) As String
If str.Contains(",")
Return "True"
Else
Return "False"
End If
End Function
```

Any suggestion on how to handle `#Error` in SSRS? thanks

Comment: why it is `Parameters!ProductID.Value(0)` - If you are using multiple values then you can use Join to check your condition. something like `Join(Parameters!ProductID.Value,",")`

Comment: I am not sure why this was done. I am fixing someone else's work

Comment: This line `IIF(First(Fields!ProductName.Value, "ProductHeader") is nothing` should be `IIF(ISNOTHING(First(Fields!ProductName.Value, "ProductHeader"))` .

Comment: It's probably not the problem but `IIF(Code.MultipleValues(Parameters!ProductID.Value(0))="True"` can be replaced with `IIF(Parameters!ProductID.Count > 1`. The code just checks to see if there is more than 1 value.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have completely removed the expression and pull the null logic in sql. It's working fine now. Expression was just very confusing and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Code.MultipleValues(Parameters!ProductID.Value(0))="True"
```

with

```
IndexOf(Parameters!ProductID.Value(0).ToString(),",") >= 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There are other parameters in the report that uses this code. If I change it, I will error out through out the other parameters. Can you please explain your answer?

Comment: It will be more efficient to call IndexOf - a built in function - rather than go to Code.MultipleValues. Take a copy first, then go to the actual code and do a search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a function, can you just put the IsNothing check in front of the parameter ?

```
=IIF(Code.MultipleValues(IsNothing(Parameters!ProductID.Value(0),""))="True"
```